# A Fantastical Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

This is my first time making a Riley Riddle. Feedback is much appreciated!

> My prefix is a sound like this.

> My infix sounds like a horse's sound.

> My suffix is the opposite of water.

> My whole is majestic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Disney Land

Prefix:

> "Dis" sounds like "this".

Infix:

> Horse's sound is Neigh = Ney(I think a sound indicator is missing here)

Suffix:

> Opposite of water = Land

Comment: Nicely done! Yes, I realised I was missing the sound indicator as soon as the question was posted, so full sorry about that, but yes, that is correct! Checkmark tomorrow, because of busy day and exams coming soon, so for now, have a +1 ;)

Comment: Just wondering, why do we need a sound indicator? (and what is a sound indicator?)

Comment: sound indicator meaning a homophone indicator(like in crossword clues) as the sound a horse makes is not letter-by-letter in the final answer, rather a similar-sounding group of letters is.

Comment: Okay. I can see where that could be helpful. Thanks.